# Error when I try to assign a variable to Rigidbody2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try adding Rigidbody2D to the script it keeps giving me the error CS0428: "Cannot convert method group 'GetComponent' to non-delegate type 'Rigidbody2D'. Did you intend to invoke the method?". MAybe its something im not seeing but ive went through it several times and didnt see anything wrong.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class characterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>;
    }



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is clear enough i think: "Did you intend to invoke the method?". 
You missed the parentheses after `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add brackets after Rigidbody2D like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class characterController : MonoBehaviour { 
public Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>;
}



void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 500);
    }
}
}
```

To avoid this problem again, try reading the error message carefully. For example, this problem could have been easily avoided by reading docs on GetComponents.

Comment: Here are the GetComponent docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Comment: Did this help? If it did, accept this answer. If it did not, tell me so I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the parentheses after GetComponent

```
using UnityEngine;

public class characterController : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of running the `GetComponent()` method and setting `rb` as what it returns, the code tries setting it as a delegate.